# Parcelable object with Integer member in Bundle got wrong while writeToParcel

Tags: android

I have an activity with a Bundle object as its arguments. This bundle is put with a Parcelable object which have Integer member.

Something goes wrong while this activity changes to another activity. Original activity saved its state (its arguments).

I got the error message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference
E/AndroidRuntime:     at [parcelable object].writeToParcel(user.java:55)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1416)....
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your object sometimes is null have you checked it?